# I am trying use IOS Simulator/Emulator or iOS SDK in windows PC a.Is it possible to install IOS Simulator/Emulator or iOS SDK in windows PC

Tags: ios, iphone, android-emulator

I am trying use IOS Simulator/Emulator or iOS SDK in windows PC for Mobile application Test.Is it possible to install IOS Simulator/Emulator or iOS SDK  in windows PC

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this legally but you can test your app on any platform by uploading your app on app.io and just run it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

NO, You need Apple Device (iMac, Macbook, Mac Mini) to develop iOS Applications and iPhone/iPad for Testing on devices. Apple provides Xcode it's Integrated Development Environment Tool only for the MAC. Please use Apple Devices, register for Developer program and use their resources. click on https://developer.apple.com for all the info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about the **virtual box**..?, It may fulfill your need. It will run the windows macintosh (hackintosh) on it. You can develop apps there and see your apps on simulator too. The main task is to download a working macintosh set up in a virtual box. You can get many tutorials for it on google. If you need any help, please revert to me, Thanks :)